# Перебор массива c неизвестным уровнем вложенности

Tags: php, jsonp

Как "пройти" весь массив, не зная уровней вложенности. Как определить и вернуть уровни вложенности массива?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте рекурсию.

```
<?php
$array = [1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1]]];
function processArray($array, $level = 0) {
    $level++;
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $level) . $array.PHP_EOL;
        return $array;
    }
    // Тут добавляем обработку массива

    foreach ($array as $arrayItem) {
        processArray($arrayItem, $level);
    }
}
$result = processArray($array);
```

Вывод:

```
        1
        2
        3
                1
                2
                3
                        1
```

Этот код будет обрабатывать массив любого уровня вложенности.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
function doSomething($item, $key){
    echo $key."=>".$item.PHP_EOL;
}
$array=[....];
array_walk_recursive($array, 'doSomething');
```

Comment: Массив то она весь обходит, но уровень вложенности придется где-то сохранять. Там 3-й параметр есть, думаю, можно его использовать.

Comment: @ilyaplot это да, как-то упустил про подсчет уровня. Хотя там в условии "ИЛИ"

Comment: Согласен, какой вопрос, такой и ответ :)